# RSA не дешифрует

Tags: java, криптография, rsa

Зашифровал строку методом RSA, дешифрую, а там вопросительные знаки и "кракозябра". До этого пробовал все работало. Приватный публичный ключ вроде не перепутал. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Так выглядит код дешифровки:

```
byte[] decodedPrivateKey = Base64.decode(savedText1,0);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec X509privbKey = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedPrivateKey);
privKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(X509privbKey);
editText.setText(privKey.toString());

//byte[] bytes2 = cipher2.doFinal(txt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte [] decodedMess = Base64.decode(productObject.getString("data"), 0);
Cipher decript2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
decript2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privKey);
byte[] decriptedBytes2 = decript2.doFinal(decodedMess);
String s =new String(decriptedBytes2, "UTF-8");

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64, скорее всего, вам нагадил. Рекомендую проверенный метод:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
.......

//Вот так шифрованный текст сохранять:   
String encrypted = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(encryptedBytes);
```

Вот так этот шифрованный текст расшифровать:

```
byte[] decriptedBytes2 = decript2.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(encrypted));
```